# Couldnt update my asp:gridview by sending parameter values from C# to asp:gridview update command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to use default Edit/Update function of a asp:gridview to update a data in sql. The code I wrote is below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEditProfile" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
              ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
              DataSourceID="DSAdminEdit" 
              DataKeyNames="pid, name, email, address, phone" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="false"
              AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton ="true" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="pid" HeaderText="pid"
                        SortExpression="pid"  ReadOnly="true"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name"
                        SortExpression="name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email"
                        SortExpression="email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address"
                        SortExpression="address" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone"
                        SortExpression="phone" />
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSAdminEdit" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UniversityDB %>"
                SelectCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Profile"
                UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [Profile] SET [name] = @name, [email] = @email, [address] = @address, [phone] = @phone WHERE [pid]=@pid"
                DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Profile] WHERE [pid] = @pid">

                 <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="name"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="email"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="address"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="phone"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="pid"></asp:Parameter>
            </UpdateParameters>
                <DeleteParameters>
                     <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="pid"></asp:Parameter>
                </DeleteParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the C# side is:

```
int pid = -1;
protected void gvEditProfile_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Int32.TryParse(gvEditProfile.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["pid"].ToString(), out pid);
}
protected void gvEditProfile_Updated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    String s = e.NewValues[1].ToString();
    DSAdminEdit.UpdateParameters["name"].DefaultValue = e.NewValues[0].ToString();
    DSAdminEdit.UpdateParameters["email"].DefaultValue =  e.NewValues[1].ToString();
    DSAdminEdit.UpdateParameters["address"].DefaultValue = e.NewValues[2].ToString();
    DSAdminEdit.UpdateParameters["phone"].DefaultValue = e.NewValues[3].ToString();
    DSAdminEdit.UpdateParameters["pid"].DefaultValue = pid.ToString() ;
}
```

However, this is not working, no update I am receiving even though I am assigning the updated values in RowUpdated method. I couldnt find out what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Updating and Updated methods have been removed from asp:Gridview definition as Rahul requested. However, Problem still goes on..

Comment: Why you are explicitly writing the `gvEditProfile_Updating` & `gvEditProfile_Updated` event handlers? You are using SQLDataSource and these events are not required.

Comment: But UpdateCommand is not working by default, how can I send the right parameters to the UpdateCommand SQL query then, in which method on c#?

Comment: It should automatically update using the SQLDataSource control, remove the `updating` & `updated` event handlers. Also, `rowUpdated` event is raised after the row is updated.

Comment: Rahul, I removed Updated and Updating attributes from asp:gridview definition, so we do not use the methods now. However, it is still not updating the data

Comment: Okay but why you have all columns as DataKeyNames? It should uniquely identify the row. I guess you should only have `pid` there.

Comment: It works!! There was only pid in DataKeyNames before. I changed it in order to fix something but it caused another problem :) Thank you very much, Rahul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment since you are using the built-in `SQLDataSource` control which takes care of updation of records in gridview automatically, there is no need to explicitly attach the event handlers for Gridview `rowupdating` & `rowupdated`.

Also, since `DataKeyNames` attribute is used to uniquely identify a row in your table you should have a primary key column name there and probably it should be `pid`  by looking at your naming convention. You can change it to:-

```
DataSourceID="DSAdminEdit" DataKeyNames="pid"
```